# MySQL UPDATE if this rows exists

Tags: mysql, update

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется файл xml с описанием 8000 позиций.

Имеется таблица MySQL, в которой находятся лишь некоторые из позиций в xml.

Как построить запрос UPDATE из xml лишь с том случае, если данная позиция имеется в таблице MySQL?

UPD. Без INSERT!

Comment: Обычный update меняет строку если она есть и ничего не делает если ее нет. так что просто его используете и все.

Comment: Ага!.. То есть, несуществующие в таблице записи добавлены не будут?

Comment: нет конечно. записи могут быть добавлены только с помощью insert. А update только меняет то что есть

Comment: Спасибо большое!